# send synchrouns request angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, synchronization, angular6

i want to send synchrouns request this nested for loop in angular 6. it all for loop must wait each other response. Please give some example in https://stackblitz.com

```
protected plateInfo(debug = true) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
          if (k % 2 !== 0) {
            for (let threshBlock = 21; threshBlock < 31; threshBlock++) {
              if (threshBlock % 2 !== 0) {
                for (let treshWeight = 5; treshWeight < 19; treshWeight++) {
                  if (treshWeight % 2 !== 0) {
                   this.getPLateInfo.getInfoPlate({
                      qausLast: i,
                      qausParam: k,
                      treshBlock: threshBlock,
                      treshWeight: treshWeight
                    }).subscribe(_data => {
                      this.result.push(_data)
                      _data.input1 = i
                      _data.input2 = k
                    })
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please don't add random trash to your post to bypass SE quality restrictions. Instead, add actual details. See also [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a

> concatMap does not subscribe to the next observable until the previous
>   completes,

```
from([your source array])
    .pipe(
        concatMap(
            (item in your array) => {
                return this.getPLateInfo.getInfoPlate(....
            }
        )
    )
    .subscribe(
        (received data from your api call) => {
            process received data here...
        }
    );
```

import them from:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

More info on concatMap [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html).

**EDIT:**

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-td35r2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Your original "plateInfo" function will make more than 1000 api calls, I hope you know what you are doing.

Anyway, I had to limit the number of items in the array to keep stackblitz site responsive.

Comment: Please give some example in https://stackblitz.com

Answer (score 0):

**Try using await/async**

```
async getResult(): MyCustomObject {
    if (typeof this.result === 'undefined') 
    {
        // save result
        this.result = await this.service.call()
        .toPromise()
        .then(resp =>resp as MyCustomObject);//Do you own cast here

    }
    return this.result;
}
```

Comment: but i use angular 6

Comment: Yes, $q is for AngularJS

Comment: but how to wait callback result this nested for loop