# Run an array of http calls sequentially in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've seen this asked a few times but I can't work out how to implement this to solve my issue.

I've basically got an array of http calls that I need to execute in sequentially order. Specifically I need to execute one, wait for it to return then execute the next.

```
let requests = [
  this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/api/value', 'one'),
  this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/api/value', 'two'),
  this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/api/value', 'three'),
  this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/api/value', 'four'),
];
```

So I'm currently using a forkJoin but this runs the requests simultaneously which is not what I want.

```
forkJoin(observableBatch).subscribe(result => {
  // success
}, error => {
  // log error
});
```

I read using `concatMap` might be the answer but how do I use this on an array of observables?

Comment: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/concat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RxJS wait for previous execution to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56804041/rxjs-wait-for-previous-execution-to-finish)

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56156720/2050306

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try  with **[concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html)**  function of RXJS, try this

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs';

let requests = [
  this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/api/value', 'one'),
  this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/api/value', 'two'),
  this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/api/value', 'three'),
  this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/api/value', 'four'),
];

concat(...requests).subscribe(result => {
  // success
}, error => {
  // log error
});
```

Comment: import { concat } from 'rxjs'. It's not an operator. And you're missing the call to subscribe.

Comment: Will the subscribe result be hit for each one of those four calls or just once all four have executed?  I've a scenario where I need the response eTag to send in the header of the subsequent request

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [concatMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/concatMap) if by "sequentially" you mean the next http request doesn't request until the response is received from the previous.

```
let requests = [
  this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/api/value', 'one'),
  this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/api/value', 'two'),
  this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/api/value', 'three'),
];

const observer = {
  complete: () => {
    // code here for when all requests complete
  },
  error: (err: any) => {
    console.error(`error in concatMap observer`, err);
  }
};

from(requests).pipe(concatMap((request) => {
  return request;
})).subscribe(observer);
```